# Ti-nspire CX Wrong Derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculator

I have this equation: $y=Cxe^{-2x}$

I worked out the first derivative and checked with wolfram alpha to get: $y=Ce^{-2x}+-2Cxe^{-2x}$

But when I try and get the first derivative in my calculator, I get:
$-2Cxe^{-2x}$ without the first term.

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the result you get if you write $Cxe^{-2x}$ and forget to enter $\times$ (times) between the $x$ and the $e^{-2x}$. It treats the first $x$ as a constant.

p.s. I verified this with my own N-Spire.

Comment: Ahh, I see, you are right. I have one more quick question. When typing the derivative out correctly in the equation, I get: $(C-2Cx)*e^{-2x}$. Simple distribution will get what I work out by hand, but is there a calculator function I can do to distribute about the numbers regardless? Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the answer to that.

Comment: @Someone I believe the calculator's "expand()" function will do what you want.